# checkout a specific tag with git subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree, git-tag

Can I use tags in subtrees? Following a specific issue:

I have a git repository which includes an external repository as a subtree.
I could add this external repository and checkout a specific branch from this repo. With `git subtree pull --prefix=<dir> --squash <remote> <branch>` the update from the selected branch works well.

Now is it possible to checkout a specific tag? I couldn't find some information about tags in subtrees...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually any reference should work. The man page for subtree displays this.

```
git subtree pull  -P <prefix> <repository> <ref>
```

Where `<ref>` can be a SHA, tag or branch. Basically anything git can resolve to a commit.

Comment: Nice, thank you very match for your answer! It works quite easy! :) (and sorry for my delayed response)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

***git subtree pull  --prefix repository ref --squash*** if you used squash originally . I used a tag in place of ref without squash after first pull and got *fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories* as the original pull had squash.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to checkout my subtree on a specific tag or branch, using :

```
git subtree pull --prefix=my_subtree_dir my_remote tags/my_tag
```

I get the following log :

```
From ../remotes_dir/my_remote
* tag               my_tag     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

But actually , nothing is done ! Not a single file is "checkout".

I managed to work around the problem by git removing my subtree files and read-tree them again from my remote repo :

```
git rm -r lib3dsp
git read-tree --prefix=lib3dsp/ -u tags/my_tag
```

Here is how I configured my subtree :

```
git remote add <my_remote>
git fetch <my_remote>
git merge -sours --no-commit <my_remote>/master
git read-tree --prefix=<my_subtree_dir> -u <my_remote>/master
git commit -m "merge <my_subtree> repo"
```