# update a specific tag with git subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree

the similar question is [checkout a specific tag with git subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411468/checkout-a-specific-tag-with-git-subtree) . howere what I do is 

`git remote add next https://github.com/iissnan/hexo-theme-next
git subtree add --prefix=themes/next  next tags/v5.1.0 --squash`

till now everythin is ok, but when I want to update the subtree to 5.1.3 using

`git subtree pull --prefix=themes/next  next tags/v5.1.3`

I get

`From https://github.com/iissnan/hexo-theme-next
 * tag               v5.1.3     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.`

I am sure there is tag 5.1.3, so how can I update to it?

Answer (score 1):

finally, I solved this by

`git subtree add --prefix=themes/next  next master --squash`

and then I can pull a specified tag